# How to solve indefinite integral of $e^{t\left(\pi \:-r\right)}\left(-\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}$?

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, indefinite-integrals

I have the following integral:
$$
\int e^{t\left(\pi -r\right)}\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\mathrm{d}t.
$$
I am not sure if this is solvable. I have tried integration by parts but do not know how to handle the term
$$
\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}
$$ due to the presence of the exponent $1-\frac{1}{n}$. Also, I can't see if Feynman Integration (if this becomes a definite integral with bounds from $0$ to infinity) would apply here. I would be grateful for any help resolving this.

Comment: Could you tell what is $s$ ?

Comment: $s=f(t)$ is a function of $t$. $ds/dt$ may also be written as $f'(t)$

Comment: $ \int \:e^{t\left(\pi -r\right)}\left(-\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}dt$ is not an equation because there is no $=$ in it.

Comment: No, I am just trying to evaluate the integral (e.g. $\int \sin(x) dx=-\cos(x)+C$).

Comment: Where did you find it? If $s=f(t)$, can we know $f(t)$? have you tried power series?

Comment: It's an equation that I found myself (modelling a system). $f(t)$ is unknown. How would I apply a power series?

Answer (score 1):

The integral actually has a a simple solution:

$$\int e^{t(\pi-r)}\left(-\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^{1-1/n}dt=(-1)^{1-1/n}\int e^{t(\pi-r)}(s'(t))^{1-1/n}dt$$

This is because $\frac{ds}{dt}$ is in a derivative form, and can be represented without raising $dt$ to a power.

For example: if $n=1$, $s(t)=t$, and $r=\pi-1$, then:

$$\int e^{t(\pi-r)}\left(-\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^{1-1/n}dt=\int e^tdt=e^t+C$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am looking for a general form of the integral (I don't know values for $n$, $s(t)$, and $r$).

Comment: @UNOWen The integral does not generally have an elementary form.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;\dfrac{\text ds}{\text dt} = \left(\dfrac{\text dt}{\text ds}\right)^{-1},$ then the given integral can be presented via the inverse function $\;t(s):$
$$\int e^{t(\pi-r)}\left(-\dfrac{\text ds}{\text dt}\right)^{\large 1-^1/_n}\,\text dt
=-\int e^{(\pi-r)\,t(s)}\;\sqrt[\Large n]{-\dfrac{\text dt}{\text ds}}\,\text ds.$$

However, detalization of $\;s(t)\;$ or $\;t(s)\;$ looks nesessary.